# c++ pointer never initialized still outputs as initialized

Tags: c++

All I am doing is declaring a pointer and then checking if its pointing to anything:

```
#pragma once

#include <Node.h>
#include <stdio.h>

template <class NodeDataType>
class LinkedList
{
typedef Node<NodeDataType>* pNode;

private:    
pNode pHead;


pNode pTail;



public:

void Add(NodeDataType* pNodeTypeData)
{


    if(pHead)
    {
        printf("phead is initialized\n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("phead is not initialized\n");

    }               
}


};
```

then, in `main()`, I am making a new LinkedList object, and calling `Add`
but when i run it, it outputs `pHead is initialized` ?
but i never initialized it?

can someone explain it to me?

thanks

(main)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <LinkedList.h>
#include <GameObject.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{

LinkedList<GameObject> meList;


meList.Add(new GameObject());


return 0;
}
```

Comment: There can be several things wrong here, please post the code in main also so that we can see the error for ourselves

Comment: look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1910832/why-arent-pointers-initialized-with-null-by-default

Comment: Does it ouputs `initialized` or `uninitialized`. Because you never initialize `pHead` but checking it in `if (pHead)`.

Comment: it outputs initialized, even though i never did.

Comment: Could you please copy the whole output.

Comment: just outputs: phead is initialized. nothing else, but i after reading what andrew linked it seems to be because c++ apparently just doesn't initialize pointers to null when they are declared, so ill have to do it myself i guess

Comment: Ah sorry I thought you are talking about compiler output, I didn't read it accurately... Now I see it is your output... If you do **not** initialize variables they are uninitialized which means they contain the value that lie at the memory address where the variable lie. It does **not** get overridden by zeroes. This applies for POD types because they don't have a standard constructor like classes. The comment of Andrew Kashpur is pointing also in that direction!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not initialise `pHead` or `pTail` in constructor or in place. So, these members will have arbitrary values when you create a `LinkedList` object. So, either write the constructor:

```
LinkedList()
    :pHead(NULL), pTail(NULL)
{
}
```

Or initialize them in-place if you are using c++11:

```
private:    
    pNode pHead = nullptr;
    pNode pTail = nullptr;
```

Comment: I would also use `nullptr` in the initializer list `:pHead(nullptr), pTail(nullptr)`.

Comment: @AndreKampling : If OP is using C++11, yes.

Comment: Yes sure you're right but using at least the `NULL` macro would be more clear then. But he could also provide an own `nullptr` type [see here at SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44517878/8051589) if his compiler doesn't support it.