# Deleting dynamically allocated variables setting pointer to 0

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, memory-management, dynamic-allocation

I can't understand the end of this code (`array = 0;`):

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Enter a positive integer: ";
    int length;
    std::cin >> length;

    int *array = new int[length];

    std::cout << "I just allocated an array of integers of length " << length << '\n';

    array[0] = 5; // set element 0 to value 5

    delete[] array; // use array delete to deallocate array
    array = 0; // use nullptr instead of 0 in C++11

    return 0;
}
```

At the end, a dynamically allocated array is deleted (returned to OS) and then assigned a value of 0.

Why is this done? After array has been returned to the OS, there is no need to assign it a value of 0, right?

Code from: http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/6-9a-dynamically-allocating-arrays/

Comment: It sets a valid (but null) pointer to array to avoid to have dangling pointer. So later, we can test `array` before to use it. if the pointer is no longer used, it is indeed unneeded.

Comment: int *array, as a pointer, still holds info on address it pointed to, even though objects are deallocated. Since that space no longer belongs to that pointer, set it to 0 so that you can't access some random data.

Comment: Using `std::vector` would avoid those manual memory management.

Comment: Variables are only known at compile time. You are deleting *values*

Comment: Read the C++ core guidlines: [R.11: Avoid calling new and delete explicitly](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md#Rr-newdelete)

Comment: In this specific case it is redundant but some people like to do this after `delete` as a general rule

Comment: I would just skip this and continue with [Chapter 6.16 - An introduction to std::vector](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/6-16-an-introduction-to-stdvector/)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> After array has been returned to the OS, there is no need to assign it a value of 0, right?

You're right it is not needed because the memory is freed (deallocated) by the [operator `delete`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/operator_delete). But think of a case where you may use the pointer in another place in your code (functions, loops, etc.) after you use `delete[]` on it.

The `array` variable still holds the address of the old allocation after the `delete[]` statement was called [(dangling pointer)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dangling_pointer). If you would access that address you would get [undefined bahaviour (UB)](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub) because the memory is no longer yours, in most of the cases your program would crash.

To avoid that you do a [null pointer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_pointer) check like:

```
if (array != nullptr)
{
   /* access array */
   ...
}
```

which is checking the pointer against the address 0 which represents an invalid address.

To make that check possible you set the pointer to [`nullptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/nullptr) or [`NULL`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/NULL) if C++11 is not available. The `nullptr` keyword introduces type safety because it acts like a pointer type and should be preferred over the C-like `NULL`. In pre C++11 `NULL` is defined as integer 0, since C++11 it's an alias to `nullptr`.
To define your own `nullptr` to use it for pre C++11 compiler look here: [How to define our own nullptr in c++98?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44517878/8051589)

---

An interesting fact about `delete` or `delete[]` is that it is safe to use it on a `nullptr`. It is written at point 2 on [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/operator_delete) or at this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6731484/8051589).

> **operator delete, operator delete[]**
>
> 2)
>   [...] The behavior of the standard library implementation of this function is undefined unless `ptr` is a null pointer or is a pointer previously obtained from the standard library implementation of `operator new[](size_t)` or operator `new[](size_t, std::nothrow_t)`.

Comment: Yes, **if** your design calls for reuse of pointers, then you need a flag to tell you that the pointer does not point to something valid; that's what a null pointer is for. It should **not** be automatically used after deleting something. In particular, it's silly to write a destructor that deletes an allocated block then sets the pointer to null, but that's often seen in beginners' code.

Comment: @PeteBecker Why would that be silly? Isn't it good practice to always null your pointers after delete, in case reuse is introduced later? What's the downside?

Comment: @Sossisos -- the reason that it's **silly** is that after the destructor runs the object **does not exist** and there **is no pointer** to reuse. The downside is that it makes whoever wrote that code look like they code by slogan instead of thinking.

Comment: @PeteBecker Ah, my apologies, I misread, I thought the "silly" was in regards to nulling pointers as a matter of course, not specifically doing it in the destructor. Anyway, I read some of the linked articles here on why nulling shouldn't be done as a matter of course, and understand the reasoning now (even though I don't quite agree with it). Thank you for your time :)

Answer (score 9):

We are setting pointers to `NULL` (0) to avoid dangling pointers (pointer is still pointing to same memory which is no longer yours). In case of local variables it is not that useful if function doesnt continue after delete (so its obvious pointer won't be reused). In case of global/member poitners its good practice to avoid bugs.

Accessing already deleted pointer may lead to overwriting/reading random memory (it might be more dangerous than crash) and causes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), while accessing `NULL` pointer will immediatelly crash.

Since [c++11](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b11) you should use `nullptr` because its defined as pointer type while `NULL` is more `int` type and improves type safety + resolves ambiguous situations.

In case of double deleting pointer, its safe to use delete on `nullptr` and nothing happens but if you delete already deleted non-null pointer, it will cause [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) and most likely program will crash.

In [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) you should avoid using pure pointers since there are STL containers (which frees their resources them self ([RAII](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2321511/what-is-meant-by-resource-acquisition-is-initialization-raii))) for this usage or [smart pointers](https://cs.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smart_pointer).

```
std::vector<int> array{1,2,3,4,5};
```

Comment: Re: "good practice to avoid bugs" -- best practice to avoid bugs is to **design** code properly and **implement** the design. Automatically setting pointers to null _just in case someone gets careless_ does **not** avoid bugs; **designing** and **implementing** a system that uses null to signify that a pointer points to nothing does.

Answer (score 3):

This is done so that the pointer is set to `NULL` (whether in C++, we prefer [nullptr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1282295/what-exactly-is-nullptr), since `NULL` and 0 may be different things).

This tactic eliminates the possibility of a *dangling pointer*, because the array may have been deleted, but that doesn't mean that it's set to `NULL`.

If we don't do that, we run the risk of checking whether the pointer is `NULL` or not (latter in our code), we will see that it's not `NULL`, wrongly believe that the pointer is OK to be accessed, and cause Undefined Behavior.

Comment: It should be set to nullptr. In C++ nullptr, NULL and 0 are different things

Comment: @ArtemyVysotsky good point, answer updated.

Answer (score 1):

You assign to a value commonly known as "invalid address", i.e. `NULL`, `0` or the pointer type `nullptr`, because otherwise there is no way you can know whether you pointer points to an invalid address. In other words when you `delete[]` your array your pointer "doesn't know" that it is pointing to a no longer usable memory address.