# Can we return false when the return type is declared as a ListNode<T>*

Tags: c++, arduino

I'm not a C++ programmer, so given this function (you may recognise it), is it valid to return false when the return type is declared as ListNode* ?

The compiler complains, but searching for a solution it seems the IDE gets the blame. I just want to understand if this is allowed and so the IDE is at fault, or if this is actually a bug.

If it helps, this is Arduino code, and i'm using IDE version 1.8.11

```
template<typename T>
ListNode<T>* LinkedList<T>::getNode(int index) {
  int _pos = 0;
  ListNode<T>* current = root;
  // Check if the node trying to get is
  // immediatly AFTER the previous got one
  if(isCached && lastIndexGot <= index) {
    _pos = lastIndexGot;
    current = lastNodeGot;
  }
  while(_pos < index && current) {
    current = current->next;
    _pos++;
  }
  // Check if the object index got is the same as the required
  if(_pos == index) {
    isCached = true;
    lastIndexGot = index;
    lastNodeGot = current;
    return current;
  }
  return false;
}
```

compiler reports:

```
cannot convert bool the ListNode<Device*>*
```

Here is an example where this function is invoked;

```
template<typename T>
bool LinkedList<T>::add(int index, T _t) {
  if(index >= _size)
    return add(_t);
  if(index == 0)
    return unshift(_t);
  ListNode<T> *tmp = new ListNode<T>(),
    *_prev = getNode(index-1);
  tmp->data = _t;
  tmp->next = _prev->next;
  _prev->next = tmp;
  _size++;
  isCached = false;
  return true;
}
```

Again, not being a c++ programmer I don't understand this code. 
It looks like `*_prev` is assigned the result of `getNode(index-1)`, which could be false.
Then it looks like it tries to access `_prev->next`. But would `_prev` be false, or `*_prev` be false? I don't understand it.

Comment: If your function returns a `ListNode<T>*`, what should `return false;` do?

Comment: `false` is not a pointer.  Maybe you want to return `NULL` instead?

Comment: yes, sorry this is probably a really bad question. This is not my code. But it feels like return false is not valid and therefore a bug. I think earlier versions of IDE just output a warning but newer IDE reports as an error and will not compile.

Comment: Do arduinos support C++11? Asking for `nullptr`.

Comment: @srayner I guess it should return `nullptr` instead of false.

Comment: @sweenish gcc is used there so it should, but it depends how the version of arduino IDE used by OP invokes gcc and if such IDE is even used, Checked there https://www.arduino.cc/en/Main/ReleaseNotes looks like Arduino IDE is using gcc 5.4.0 since 1.8.6

Comment: please include the compiler error in the question. If the compiler tells you that there is something wrong with the code, then in 99.9% of all cases there is something wrong with the code

Comment: Looks like code originates for here; https://www.arduinolibraries.info/libraries/linked-list if anyone is interested in the whole context

Comment: return nullptr seems to compile, but I have no idea what effect this would have

Comment: You said the compiler reports "`cannot convert bool the ListNode<Device*>*`". That's not the exact error message. It's always best to copy-and-paste the error message rather than re-typing it. Small errors can be significant.

Answer (score 2):

You really should not `return false;` there. What you want to do is `return nullptr;` or `return NULL;` if `nullptr` is not available. The reason why this was only an warning in the past is probably that you used an older c++ standard in the past. On my system, you get the following for different c++ standards:

Code:

```
int* test() {
    return false;
}

int main() {
    test();
}
```

Output:

```
$ clang++ -std=c++98 test.cpp -Wall -Wextra 
test.cpp:2:12: warning: initialization of pointer of type 'int *' to null from a constant boolean expression [-Wbool-conversion]
    return false;
           ^~~~~
1 warning generated.
$ clang++ -std=c++03 test.cpp -Wall -Wextra 
test.cpp:2:12: warning: initialization of pointer of type 'int *' to null from a constant boolean expression [-Wbool-conversion]
    return false;
           ^~~~~
1 warning generated.
$ clang++ -std=c++11 test.cpp -Wall -Wextra 
test.cpp:2:12: error: cannot initialize return object of type 'int *' with an rvalue of type 'bool'
    return false;
           ^~~~~
1 error generated.
```

It seems there was a change to this in the C++11 standard. I am not sure what exactly changed there, the only change I know from C++11 regarding conversions are explicit operators, maybe someone else can say something to this regard.

Comment: If `nullptr` is not available you can define an own `nullptr` like here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44517878/8051589.